# i want to apply oversampling to the minority classes.but it displayes an error code

Tags: tensorflow2.0, oversampling, imagedatagenerator

I have a datasets which is imbalanced between normal and abnormal ultrasound liver images.I want to balance the datasets using imageDatagenerator packages but it displays an error
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'oversample'

```
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    samplewise_center=True,
    samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    rotation_range=90,
    brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5],
    zoom_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    oversample='majority')
```

Comment: What is your tensorflow version?

Comment: iam using tensorflow version 2.9.2

Comment: There is no `oversample` in `ImageDataGenerator` in 2.9.2. Your code belongs to the much older version: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator